# What is the size of a "point" unit in Esri software?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, units

When creating point symbology with Esri software, we can use points, in, cm, or mm as a unit of measurement.

Due to the fact that there are a few definitions of a "pt" or point, which of the following definitions should be used?

1. Didot point (0.376065 mm)
2. Pica point (0.3514 mm)
3. DTP point (0.3528 mm)

Comment: For what it's worth, I've always heard the units referred to as points and picas - I've never heard 'pica point'. I'd also never heard of Didots either, but I don't study typography that much. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)) (for whatever that's worth) notes that DTP has been established as "the *de facto* standard".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Point sizes are..

*Points are a standard graphic measurement unit equal to 1/72 of an inch*

or in metric 0.352778 mm

So DTP point is the answer to your question.

http resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/samples/Cartography/Labeling_and_Annotation/PointSizeCalculator/a2b8686d-673f-4954-92c8-8f2568125164.htm

2022 edit as website no longer exists
https://web.archive.org/web/20170309040123/http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/samples/Cartography/Labeling_and_Annotation/PointSizeCalculator/a2b8686d-673f-4954-92c8-8f2568125164.htm

This is a VBA Tool for calculating point sizes at set scales

Point Size at Map Scale Calculator
http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/samples/Cartography/Labeling_and_Annotation/PointSizeCalculator/visual_basic/frmconversion.frm.htm

Comment: The above links to ESRI and ArcGIS resources do not work any more.

Comment: @TomazicM Thanks, suggest users point to old webpages using the waybackmachine, as ESRI can change their links at anytime, here is the first link https://web.archive.org/web/20170309040123/http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/samples/Cartography/Labeling_and_Annotation/PointSizeCalculator/a2b8686d-673f-4954-92c8-8f2568125164.htm